# How to display a map using WebView

Tags: webview

I have a Basic4PPC program that displays Bing (or Google) static maps in a WebBrowser, simply with one statement: WEB1.Navigate(URLStr).

Now, I try to do the same in Basic4Android using a WebView view, as follows:

In the designer I added WebView1, 0,0,480,480

Under Globals: Dim WebView1 as WebView

Under Activity_Create: WebView1.Initialize("WebView1")

In a sub GetMap:WebView1.LoadUrl(URLStr)

Finally in Sub WebView1_PageFinished(WEBStr)

```
Freeze(False)
MapLoaded=True
CBNavigate.RequestFocus
```

End Sub

I get the impression data some data traffic occurs; but no map is shown.

I searched the WEB for a simple demo of the use of WebView but only find a lot of Java stuff, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use 'basic4android' tag for Basic4android related questions. See this [link](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/9005-googlemaps-v3-webview.html) for an example of using WebView with google maps.